# why glibc memcpy not choose avx512 version?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, glibc, avx512

I compile a sample code in following:

```
 #cat array_addition.c 
 #define MAX 1000000
 #define S 1024
 #include <string.h>
int a[S], b[S], c[S];

__attribute__((target_clones("avx512f", "avx2","arch=atom","default")))
void foo(int argc){
    int i,x;

for (x=0; x<1024; x++){
    for (i=0; i<S; i++){
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
    }
}
    b[0] = argc;
    memcpy(&a[0], &b[0], argc *sizeof(int));
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

which call memcpy;

from the objdump, we can found it will call GLIBC memcpy:

```
#readelf -r a.out 

Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x418 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000403ff8  000200000006 R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0

Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x430 contains 4 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000404018  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
000000404020  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000404028  000300000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 memcpy@GLIBC_2.14 + 0
000000404030  000000000025 R_X86_64_IRELATIV                    4018f0
```

then, i use gdb to trace which glibc implementation it used;

```
(gdb) b memcpy@plt    
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401050
(gdb) s
The program is not being run.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401050 in memcpy@plt ()
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function memcpy@plt,
which has no line number information.
0x00007ffff7b623a0 in __memcpy_ssse3_back () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) info function __memcpy_*
All functions matching regular expression "__memcpy_*":

Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007ffff7aa2840  __memcpy_chk_sse2
0x00007ffff7aa2850  __memcpy_sse2
0x00007ffff7ab1b40  __memcpy_chk_avx512_no_vzeroupper
0x00007ffff7ab1b50  __memcpy_avx512_no_vzeroupper
0x00007ffff7b23360  __memcpy_chk
0x00007ffff7b5a470  __memcpy_chk_ssse3
0x00007ffff7b5a480  __memcpy_ssse3
0x00007ffff7b62390  __memcpy_chk_ssse3_back
0x00007ffff7b623a0  __memcpy_ssse3_back
(gdb)
```

there are __memcpy_avx512_no_zeroupper, but not been choosen;

and my cpu supports its feature:

> Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep
> mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht
> tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs
> bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq
> dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm
> pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes
> xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3
> cdp_l3 invpcid_single pti intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp
> tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1
> hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq
> rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl
> xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total
> cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts pku ospke flush_l1d

gcc version:

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=gcc
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/china-gcc-10.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
> Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu Configured with: ./configure
> --prefix=/root/china-gcc-10.2.0 --disable-multilib Thread model: posix Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)

Comment: Glibc is free software. You are allowed to download its source code, study it, and improve it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On "mainstream" CPUs like Skylake-X and IceLake, it's only worth using 512-bit vectors at all if you use them consistently for a lot of your program's run-time, not just for an occasional memcpy.  (And also if your program will run for a long time, otherwise you're slowing down other processes that share the same physical core via context switches and/or hyperthreading.)  See [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56852812) for the details: you don't want occasional calls to memcpy to hold your CPU frequency down to a lower max turbo.

Using AVX-512 features with 256-bit vectors (AVX-512VL) can be worth it for some things, e.g. if masking is nice, or if you use YMM16..31 to avoid VZEROUPPER.

I'd guess that glibc would only resolve memcpy to `__memcpy_avx512_no_vzeroupper` on systems like Knight's Landing (KNL) Xeon Phi, where the CPU is designed around AVX-512, and there's no downside to using 512-bit ZMM vectors.  There's no need for vzeroupper even after using ymm0..15 on KNL.  In fact vzeroupper is very slow on KNL, and definitely something to avoid, hence putting `no_vzeroupper` in the function name.

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-avx512-no-vzeroupper.S.html is the source for that version.  It uses ZMM vectors, including ZMM0..15, so if used on a Skylake/IceLake CPU it *should* use vzeroupper.  **This version looks designed for KNL.**

---

There would be some tiny benefit to having an AVX-512VL version that used ymm16..31 to avoid vzeroupper (to speed 32 .. 64 byte copies), without ever using ZMM registers.

And it would make sense for `__memcpy_avx512_no_vzeroupper` to only use ZMM16..31 so avoiding vzeroupper isn't a problem on mainstream CPUs; then it would be a usable option in code that already made heavy use of AVX-512 (and thus was already paying the CPU-frequency cost.)

Comment: so the __memcpy_sse3 is best for my cpu? if the memory to cpy is very large, does glibc use a more high performance method like vmovntq ? hope to clarify the strategy to choose different implementation :)

Comment: @Chinaxing: I would have expected `__memcpy_avx_unaligned_erms` on your Skylake-X system, same as my Skylake desktop. (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-avx-unaligned-erms.S.html).  Perhaps your distro misconfigured glibc to omit and AVX1 / `rep movsb` version.  The `ssse3` version avoids even 256-bit vectors.

Comment: does this depends on glibc version ? i use glibc 2.17. maybe too old ?

Comment: @Chinaxing: Unlikely; your glibc is new enough to have AVX512 after all!  AVX1 existed for several years before that, since about 2011.

Comment: @PeterCordes as of very recently because of `vzeroupper` aborting transactions they added a `zmm16...31` version of nearly all string functions. [Memmove commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=e4fda4631017e49d4ee5a2755db34289b6860fa4)

Comment: Very interesting question and answer. +1