# AVX512 compare to vector not to mask

Tags: x86-64, avx512

I miss the compare instructions in avx2 that produce a vector instead of a mask. What is the most efficient way to accomplish the same thing in avx512? Is it _mm512_cmp_ps_mask followed by an expand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think just compare and [`vpmovm2d`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovm2b:vpmovm2w:vpmovm2d:vpmovm2q), although very often you can use merge-masking or zero-masking (possibly with a `set1(-1)` constant) for the next step, instead of whatever you were going to do with a vector.  e.g. for counting matches, instead of `_mm_sub_epi32()` with the vector 0/-1 compare result, just do a merge-masked add.

Of course, for 256-bit vectors, the AVX2 compare instructions are still usable.  Probably not worth it to unpack halves of a 512-bit vector, but it's sometimes worth it to avoid 512-bit vectors entirely with AVX-512 (e.g. to avoid [clock-speed penalties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency) on some CPUs, and also to avoid the shutdown of the vector ALU on port 1).  So you still take advantage of the useful new instructions in AVX-512, and the extra registers (x/ymm16..31) for operands that don't need to be used with VEX-coded AVX1/AVX2-only instructions.

Still, there are cases where it might be worthwhile to just accept the penalty of needing to turn a mask back into a vector in order to use 512-bit vectors.