# Convert 128 bit AVX register with 8-bit elements to two 256 bit registers with 32-bit elements

Tags: performance, x86, simd, avx, avx2

I am reading 16 bytes of data in to a `__m128i` register and processing as 8 bit elements.

Later I need to convert the 16x 8-bit elements in to 16x 32-bit elements.

Obviously this requires 512 bits of storage. However, I presume it's best to avoid AVX 512 as it will reduce the CPU frequency?

Is it possible to convert 16x 8-bit elements from `__m128i` to two `__256i` registers, each containing 8x 32-bit elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way is two `vpmovzxbd ymm,xmm` instructions (or `sx` to sign-extend), [asm manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovzx).  Unfortunately it can only read from the bottom of a vector, so it would take an extra shuffle to get the high 8 bytes of your input lined up.  But until AVX-512, there are no lane-crossing shuffles with byte granularity.  (`vpermb` which would need a vector constant and a mask constant to do this in one instruction).

```
  __m256i lo = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(v);
  __m256i hi = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi64(v,v));  // vpunpckhqdq + vpmovzxbd
```

`vpunpckhqdq` can run on port 1 or 5 on Ice Lake, so it doesn't compete for the main shuffle unit on port 5 that `vpmovzx* ymm, xmm` needs.  https://uops.info/.

AMD Zen doesn't handle `vpmovzxbd` fully efficiently (single uop) until Zen 4.  It might possibly be worth doing `vinserti128` and 2x `vpshufb` with two different vector constants, if you're mainly tuning for AMD.

---

If you had just loaded this `__m128i` from memory, you could instead do a 128-bit broadcast-load, `vbroadcasti128 ymm, [mem]`.  Intrinsics for this are inconsistently and poorly designed, with the intrinsics for `vbroadcastf128` taking a `__m128 const *` or `__m128d const *` pointer (not `float*`) but the `vbroadcasti128` intrinsic taking `__m128i` by value despite the fact that the instruction only works with a memory source operand.  So it requires the compiler to fold a `_mm_loadu_si128` into the broadcast, or would tempt a compiler into spilling/reloading a `__m128i`, or into using `vinserti128` to shuffle a register instead.

```
   const __m256i vbcst = _mm256_broadcastsi128_si256(_mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)addr));
   const __m128i v = _mm256_castsi256_si128(vbcst);  // try to convince the compiler to just use the low half for whatever you need

   __m256i lo = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(v);       // or with a different shuffle mask if optimizing for AMD
   __m256i hi = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(vbcst, mask);  // byte shuffle within each 128-bit half, which can also zero elements.
```

---

> However, I presume it's best to avoid AVX 512 as it will reduce the CPU frequency?

Much smaller penalty in Ice Lake than in previous generations, but any need for a frequency/voltage transition causes a significant stall when it happens.  (But then if you keep using 512-bit vectors, it'll stay at the new speed/voltage for the rest of the program). See  [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency)

Also, it's only 512-bit vector width that can cause a penalty, not a zero-masking `vpermb ymm` that requires AVX-512 VBMI + VL.  (Getting a constant into a mask register would also cost a uop, so it might not save anything unless you're doing this in a loop.)

```
   __m256i lo = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(v);
#ifdef __AVX512VBMI__      // Ice Lake / Zen 4
   __m256i hi = _mm256_maskz_permutexvar_epi8(0x11111111, _mm256_setr_epi32(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), v);
#else
  ...
#endif
```

If you can't make effective use of 512-bit vectors for most of your program, yes, it's often better to only use 256-bit vectors.  (Or if you're sharing a CPU with other work, by other threads or other processes.)  But that shouldn't stop you from using AVX-512's new shuffles and features when they're useful with 256-bit vectors, if you can assume they're available.  (If you'd have to make a different version of the function and dispatch based on run-time detection of AVX-512, it might not be worth it.)

Comment: Hi Peter. I am only coding for Intel. Yes I am populating the initial `__m128i` from unaligned bytes in memory.

Comment: Regarding AVX512 performance degradation, what is the best way to measure this? I typically profile with `__rdtsc()` but this returns cycles. Consequently if the CPU frequency reduces, I doubt `__rdtsc()` would change. Is it best to use `chrono` high resolution clock?

Comment: @user997112: `rdtsc` counts *reference* cycles that tick at a fixed frequency, independent of core clock cycles. See [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) On Linux for example, `perf stat` is a convenient way to count the `cycles` event for a whole program, so you can see both wall-clock time and clock cycles. (And thus also average CPU frequency while running it.)

Comment: @user997112: You say "Later I need to convert the 16x 8-bit elements in to 16x 32-bit elements", so I assumed that was the result of some computation.  If it's the original bytes from memory that you need to unpack, then yeah you can use `vbroadcasti128` if you're doing this in a loop and having 1 or 2 registers holding shuffle-control vectors is a win vs. 1 extra shuffle uop.

Comment: "If it's the original bytes from memory that you need to unpack". Not 100% certain what this means, so i'll give an example of logic similar to what I am doing: I read 16 bytes in to an AVX register, let's say I then add an 8-bit integer to each element (no overflow). Then, in the next stage I multiple each 8-bit element by a 32-bit integer. Obviously now I need each 8-bit element to be expanded to 32-bits.

Comment: @user997112: If you read that middle section of my answer about the idea of using `vbroadcasti128` when you load from memory, it should be clear what the restriction is.  The byte values you want to unpack to 32-bit have to already be replicated in the high and low halves of a `__m256i`.  If you can do the 8-bit integer add on replicated data (e.g. with a replicated constant?), that could work to save one instruction later when you're shuffling.  Otherwise not.

Comment: Hi Peter, just revisiting this. So, due to `_mm256_cvtepu8_epi32` all we need to do is get the upper 64 bits of the 128, in to the lower part of the 128. I looked at the first solution but I wasn't sure how the `_mm_unpackhi_epi64(v)` was intended, as it requires a second arg and does a interleave. Is there a way to achieve this using a shift? We just want to shift bytes 8 to 15, to 0 to 7?

Comment: @user997112: I meant `_mm_unpackhi_epi64(v,v)`, thanks for spotting the typo.  There are many other ways to shuffle the top 8 bytes to the bottom of a `__m128i`, given that we don't care what ends up in the upper 8 bytes of that `__m128i`.  Possibilities include `psrldq` byte-shift, `pshufd` dword shuffle, `movhlps` (into any dummy destination, including itself), `palignr same,same,8` rotate, etc.  `vpunpckhqdq dst, same,same` is one of the most efficient on modern Intel CPUs, for instruction size (no immediate, 2-byte VEX prefix) and for being able to run on multiple execution ports.

Comment: @user997112: unpackhi_epi64 interleaves 64-bit chunks, but there's only 2 total within the 128-bit lane, so it really just concatenates high halves of the input vectors.  Smaller granularity shuffles like `_mm_unpackhi_epi16`, would interleave the data you want with data you don't, that's why I chose `epi64`.