# gcc: Enable AVX, but not for FP math

Tags: gcc, avx, avx512

Does gcc have the option to enable AVX512, but only for non-FP operations? I have the problem that my application gets much slower if AVX512 is enabled, because they seem to downclock the CPU cores.

However, lots of the code still would benefit from integer AVX optimizations, so I would like to have that still enabled. Also there the penalty should be much lower compared to FP math.

Comment: Do you mean `-mprefer-vector-width=256`, or do you still want 512 bit integer operations, but 256 bit FP operations?

Comment: [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56861355) explains the L0/L1/L2 levels of downclocking, with the worst being 512-bit "heavy" uops, in case that helps.  AFAIK, GCC only has an option to limit by vector width, not to allow 512-bit "light" instructions only.  (No FP, and no integer multiply.)

Comment: @chtz: 256 bit is also okay, but also in that case I would like to disable heavy operations, because enabling 256 bit AVX currently still results in slower code than no AVX at all