# .NET8 supports Vector512, but why doesn't Vector reach 512 bits?

Tags: c#, simd, intrinsics, avx512, .net-8.0

My CPU is AMD Ryzen 7 7840H which supports AVX-512 instruction set.  When I run the .NET8 program, the value of `Vector512.IsHardwareAccelerated` is true.  But `System.Numerics.Vector<T>` is still 256-bit, and does not reach 512-bit.
Why doesn't the `Vector<T>` type reach 512 bits in length? Is it currently unsupported, or do I need to tweak the configuration?

Example code:

```cs
TextWriter writer = Console.Out;
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Vector512.IsHardwareAccelerated:\t{0}", Vector512.IsHardwareAccelerated));
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated:\t{0}", Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated));
writer.WriteLine(string.Format("Vector<byte>.Count:\t{0}\t# {1}bit", Vector<byte>.Count, Vector<byte>.Count * 8));
```

Test results:

```
Vector512.IsHardwareAccelerated:        True
Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated:   True
Vector<byte>.Count:     32      # 256bit
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of an unfortunately deleted question from a couple months ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118399/will-c-sharp-system-numerics-namespace-run-on-avx-512-in-net8-or-in-the-near-fu -  But fortunately the key info is in a Github issue the OP of that question opened, with replies from C# / .net devs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92189 - For the same hardware reason that C compilers default to `-mprefer-vector-width=256` when auto-vectorizing large loops, C# doesn't automatically make all vectorized code use 512-bit even if it's available.

Also, for small problems, e.g. 9 floats, it could mean no vectorized iterations happen, just scalar fallback code.

Also, apparently some code-bases (hopefully accidentally) depend on Vector not being wider than 32-byte, so it would be a breaking change for those.

> @stephentoub wrote:  **In .NET 8, the variable-width `Vector<T>` will not automatically support widths greater than 256 bits.** It's likely in .NET 9 you'll be able to opt-in to that, but at present it's not clear whether it'll be enabled by default,

---

I commented on the dotnet github issue with some details about the CPU-hardware reasons; I'll reproduce some of that here:

- See [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency)
- Also https://reviews.llvm.org/D111029 including some Intel testing results that found clang auto-vectorization of SPEC2017 actually got a 1% slowdown with `-mprefer-vector-width=512` vs. `256` on Ice Lake Xeon. But again, that's LLVM auto-vectorization of scalar code, not like C# where this would only affect manually-vectorized loops, so the tuning considerations are somewhat different from `-mprefer-vector-width=256`.

In a program that frequently wakes up for short bursts of computation, its AVX-512 usage will still lower turbo frequency for the core, affecting other programs.

Things are different on Zen 4; they handle 512-bit vectors by taking extra cycles in the execution units, so as long as 512-bit vectors don't require more shuffling work or some other effect that would add overhead, 512-bit vectors are a good win for front-end throughput and how far ahead out-of-order exec can see in terms of elements or scalar iterations. (Since a 512-bit uop is still only 1 uop for the front-end.) GCC and Clang default to `-mprefer-vector-width=512` for `-march=znver4`.

There's no turbo penalty or other inherent downsides to 512-bit vectors on Zen 4 (AFAIK; I don't know how misaligned loads perform). It's just a matter of whether software can use them efficiently (without needing more bloated code for loop prologues / epilogues, e.g. scalar cleanup if a masked final iteration doesn't Just Work.) AVX-512 masked stores are efficient on Zen 4, despite the fact that AVX1/2 `vmaskmovps` / `vpmaskmovd` aren't. (https://uops.info/)

For code where you have exactly 32 bytes of something, if the 32-byte vectors are no longer an option then that's a loss. C#'s scalable vector-length model isn't ideal for those cases. ARM SVE or RISC-V Vector extensions where the hardware ISA are designed around a variable vector-length with masking to handle vectors shorter than the HW's native length, but doing the same thing for C# `Vector<>` probably wouldn't work well because lots of hardware (x86 with AVX2, or AArch64 without SVE) can't efficiently support masking for arbitrary-length stuff.

---

I wrote more about Intel on the github issue, which I'm not going to copy/paste all of here.

There can be significant overall throughput gains from 512-bit vectors for some workloads on Intel CPUs.  But it comes with downsides, like more expensive misaligned memory access.