What can cause an AVX2 dot product to perform differently for different runs?
I'm writing a dot product calculator for AVX2.  I'm trying to benchmark it, but the same program runs differently among runs.  I'm trying to find the cause.  First I suspected that data alignment may cause the problem, but even after aligning the data to 4K boundary, the issue persists.  Data is so small that it should fit into L1 cache.  My test program runs in 2.3-3.0 seconds.  But even if I increase the iteration count to 10x, the runtime varies between 23-28 sec.  I'd expect much less variation.
I have a Core i7-12800H (E-cores disabled so it's running on a Golden Cove P-core). Linux kernel 6.11, and CPU governor set to performance.  I don't think that the issue is CPU throttling, it seems that during the program runs, CPU runs at ~constant 4.7-4.8 GHz.  I did benchmarks on this computer before, results had much less variance for other code.
Here are two different perf stat results (for the same executable). The number of instructions is the same, but cycle count varies. Fast, run in 2.3 sec:
 Performance counter stats for './t':

           2328.22 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized
                32      context-switches                 #   13.744 /sec
                 6      cpu-migrations                   #    2.577 /sec
                65      page-faults                      #   27.918 /sec
       10783895775      cpu_core/cycles/                 #    4.632 GHz
       33906242851      cpu_core/instructions/           #   14.563 G/sec
        1701192939      cpu_core/branches/               #  730.685 M/sec
             18621      cpu_core/branch-misses/          #    7.998 K/sec

       2.329005509 seconds time elapsed

       2.328711000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys

Slow, run in 2.9 sec:
 Performance counter stats for './t':

           2855.76 msec task-clock                       #    1.000 CPUs utilized
                26      context-switches                 #    9.104 /sec
                 0      cpu-migrations                   #    0.000 /sec
                66      page-faults                      #   23.111 /sec
       13620027356      cpu_core/cycles/                 #    4.769 GHz
       33907381511      cpu_core/instructions/           #   11.873 G/sec
        1701481151      cpu_core/branches/               #  595.806 M/sec
             19152      cpu_core/branch-misses/          #    6.706 K/sec

       2.856294128 seconds time elapsed

       2.856142000 seconds user
       0.000000000 seconds sys

I tried both clang and gcc, same thing happens (used clang++-20 t.cpp -ot -O3 -march=haswell and g++-14 t.cpp -ot -O3 -march=haswell)
Here's my benchmark program (note, this is not a finished version, dot_product() only works correctly if length is a multiple of 64):
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <immintrin.h>

inline __m128 horizontal_sum_8(__m256 v) {
    __m128 t = _mm_add_ps(_mm256_castps256_ps128(v), _mm256_extractf128_ps(v, 1));
    t = _mm_add_ps(t, _mm_movehl_ps(t, t));
    return _mm_add_ps(t, _mm_movehdup_ps(t));
}

float dot_product(int length, const float *x, const float *y) {
    __m256 sum0 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 sum1 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 sum2 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    __m256 sum3 = _mm256_setzero_ps();
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= length - 64) {
        const __m256 x0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i);
        const __m256 x1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 8);
        const __m256 x2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 16);
        const __m256 x3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 24);
        const __m256 x4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 32);
        const __m256 x5 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 40);
        const __m256 x6 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 48);
        const __m256 x7 = _mm256_loadu_ps(x + i + 56);
        const __m256 y0 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i);
        const __m256 y1 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 8);
        const __m256 y2 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 16);
        const __m256 y3 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 24);
        const __m256 y4 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 32);
        const __m256 y5 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 40);
        const __m256 y6 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 48);
        const __m256 y7 = _mm256_loadu_ps(y + i + 56);

        sum0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x0, y0, sum0);
        sum1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x1, y1, sum1);
        sum2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x2, y2, sum2);
        sum3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x3, y3, sum3);
        sum0 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x4, y4, sum0);
        sum1 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x5, y5, sum1);
        sum2 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x6, y6, sum2);
        sum3 = _mm256_fmadd_ps(x7, y7, sum3);
        i += 64;
    }

    __m256 sum = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_add_ps(sum0, sum1), _mm256_add_ps(sum2, sum3));

    return _mm_cvtss_f32(horizontal_sum_8(sum));
}

int main() {
    const int N = 1024;
    alignas(4096) float x[N];
    alignas(4096) float y[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = 0;
        y[i] = 0;
    }

    float s = 0;
    for (int iter = 0; iter < 100'000'000; iter++) {
        s += dot_product(N, x, y);
    }

    printf("%f\n", s);
}

This uses 4 vector accumulators.  Alder Lake's P-core latency x throughput product is 4c x 2/c = 8 FMAs in flight.  (https://uops.info/).  Each FMA is fed by 2 loads.  P-core load throughput is 3 per clock, so 1.5 FMAs per clock is the theoretical peak throughput for this, but with only four dependency chains it can only average 1 FMA/clock except when it can find instruction-level parallelism between the end of one dot product and the start of the next.  Why is that so inconsistent?
If I benchmark Intel MKL's cblas_sdot function, the same thing happens, runtime varies between 2.7-3.3 sec.
What could be the explanation for this issue?  Which CPU perf counter may reveal the cause?

Edit:
I manually limited the CPU to 3.4 GHz to exclude the possibility of auto-throttling, run the program ~600 times, and created a scatter plot. It seems that the runtime has two typical values, ~3.4 sec, and ~4.2 sec. In ~60% of the cases, these two values are the result (I mean, this is the time spent in the program). In the other ~40%, values in between:

Edit 2:
I managed to run perf record, not sure if it is helpful. Left side is when run is slow, right is fast. The numbers in front of each instruction is the number of samples perf record took (I used perf record -e cycles:ppp at 4KHz). The sum of samples is 16130 (left side, slow) and 12750 (right side, fast):


Benchmarking needs to run hundred, perhaps even thousands, of times to get an accurate average. Also, have you tested a simple by plain C++ implementation and checked that the compiler can't optimize well enough for your requirements? And have you thought of parallelization with e.g. threads?

On a different note, you could skip the first initialization loop by simply initializing the arrays in place. Or use something like std::fill. The compiler and standard library is probably going to do it much better than your simple loop. Also, dot_product(N, x, y) will always return the same value inside the loop, it's invariant. What assembly code is the compiler generating for that loop? And why are you using int for things that shouldn't be negative? Use size_t for all sizes, and at least unsigned for all variables that shouldn't be negative.

Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852812/simd-instructions-lowering-cpu-frequency

@Someprogrammerdude: My program runs in ~2 seconds, does 100 million of dot products. If my computer is idle (and it is), then the run time should not vary by 20-30%. I can understand if rarely, a run is slower somewhat for some reason. But I run this program a lot of times, and this variance doesn't go away. Sometimes consistently 3 consecutive runs produce a slow value. And then 3 runs produce the fast one. Regarding initialization: The method doesn't matter, because I run the dot product 100 million times after initialization. 99.99% of the time does into the dot product.

@Someprogrammerdude: regarding dot_product is a pure function: yes, but fortunately neither gcc nor clang see this. If they optimized around this, I'd have done something about it. But the question is not this. I have a program, whose runtime varies a lot, but it should not, as it always calculates the same thing. What is the cause?

@Someprogrammerdude "Use size_t for all sizes" the argument need not be had here, but there are strong opinions against that, e.g. std::ssize.

Assuming the benchmarks are not being affected by CPU contention on a busy computer, or by anti-malware running on the computer, or by undefined behavior in the program, try running several performance profiles and see where the time is being spent.

FWIW I couldn't reproduce the timing inconsistency on my old i7 6700 (Skylake) CPU. All of 10 runs were within about 1%. I don;t think this is an issue with your program. My CPU is much older, and slower, than yours. The runs took 4s.

Are some of your runs starting on an E-core?  How fast is migration from an E-core to a P-core on newer hybrid CPUs that have them?  (@SimonGoater, Skylake is several generations before Alder Lake which introduced this complicating factor.)  Also semi-related re: amount of unrolling: Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators) - unroll by 8 is only just barely sufficient to hide FMA latency if uop scheduling goes perfectly. On my Skylake, I found more regs helped

It could be that there's a stable pattern of uop scheduling that results in wasted cycles, and another stable pattern that's good.  Not sure how to identify that; we know it's slower; only front-end vs. back-end or memory would be easy to distinguish.  Alder Lake's front-end is wider than Skylake's so uop assignment to ports can easily be different.  From your perf counters, the slow version ran at higher frequency so it's probably not due to running on an E-core.  Oh, and the counts are cpu_core not cpu_atom, which is how perf distinguishes Intel P vs. E.

@PeterCordes: no, I have E-cores disabled. But I've just found out that this has to do something with scheduling. If I start my program with taskset -c 0, then timing becomes consistent. Which is weird, because there isn't too much cpu migrations happening in the first place. My perf stat example for the slow case, it shows exacly the opposite. It has 0 cpu migrations.

Maybe interrupts are the key to getting it out of a stable but sub-optimal pattern of uop allocation to ports?  And maybe core 0 has a more frequent interrupt handler in /proc/interrupts?  Oh, or maybe competition from the other logical core sharing a physical core (hyperthreading)?  cpu_clk_thread_unhalted.one_thread_active counts at about 24MHz on my Skylake in ideal circumstances where a thread has the physical core to itself.

@PeterCordes: it seems that it doesn't matter which core I'm using. If the task is tied to whichever core, then timing becomes consistent and fast. Weird.

Oh, that is odd.  That makes my hyperthreading competition guess less likely, too.

My "just barely enough accumulators" comment was neglecting the fact that every FMA is fed by 2 loads, so you should actually bottleneck on 3 loads per clock.  How close are the slow vs. fast runs coming to that theoretical peak throughput of 3 loads and 1.5 FMAs per clock?

@PeterCordes: I might not be skilled enough to answer your question, but let's try: the main loop in dot_product runs 16 times (this is 1024/64) for each call. Overall, the loop body is executed 1.6 G times. Runtime is ~3.15 vs ~4.04 sec, CPU freq is 3.4 GHz. So each loop body needs ~6.69 vs ~8.58 cycles. But this doesn't include other costs (like horizontal_sum_8, call the function, etc.), supposedly this is why we get weird fractional numbers? Each loop does 16 loads and 8 FMAs. But I'm not sure how to add the cycles of these together. Does this make sense?

If the OoO exec window is big enough, it can hide the hsum part and have loads from the next call (or outer iteration if inlined) already in the ROB+scheduler while the hsum is finishing executing on the ALU ports.  It's load ports that are the bottleneck; extra ALU work just takes up some space in the ROB+scheduler but runs on different ports.  16 loads per 6.69c is only 2.39 loads per clock, well short of 3.0 even for the fast version.  Or 1.86 load/c for the slow version.

Oh wait, you unrolled by 8 but you only have 4 accumulators!  So you are potentially bottlenecked on FMA latency and dependency chains.  4 accumulators can keep 4 FMAs in flight, 1/clock.  Only out-of-order exec across outer loop iterations can do better than that, allowing some runs to do a bit better than the 1 FMA / 2 load per clock bottleneck you've aimed for with this code.  (IDK why that would sometimes go well and sometimes no; maybe uop port scheduling quirks).  That's also why @SimonGoater's Skylake test didn't show any variation; it just bottlenecks on 2 loads/clock.

@PeterCordes: I see, so there is optimization potential here. The whole point of this benchmark to help me optimize this code. But as it is unreliable, I cannot really do it, because I never know whether a code become faster/slower because of my changes, or because my CPU decided to run it slower for some reason... It turned out that even with locked on a core, the slow version still happens, just rarely. Of course, I can re-run the test several times, but it would be nice if the benchmark was more reliable. This issue bothers me for a long time, I've just finally decided to ask help here.

Well for sure I'd change to using 8 accumulators, more than enough to hide FMA latency while sustaining 3 loads per clock without making OoO exec work too hard.  We expect that to run pretty near the theoretical peak of 3 loads/clock without much noise, since the bottleneck is just load throughput with their addresses being ready plenty early.  That would lend some weight to my hypothesis that dep-chain bottlenecks are sensitive to small variations in which uops get scheduled to which port, and that a stable pattern can develop (since scheduling depends on number of unexecuted uops per port)

@PeterCordes: yeah, I use only 4 accumulators, because I was afraid that I run out of registers. But even if 8 accumulators are not possible (not sure, I'll surely check it, thanks for the suggestion), maybe I can use 6. It doesn't have to be a power of two :)

x86-64 has 16 XMM/YMM registers.  You can use up to 15 accumulators without spills/reloads if the compiler does a good job.  (Memory-source FMA instructions like vfmadd231ps ymm0, tmp, [src] just need one temporary YMM for the other load feeding the FMA.)  You can use up to 12 or 14 accumulators without much risk of the compiler making a mess.  6 would only just barely be enough to hide FP latency at 3 loads per clock (1.5 FMAs/clock x 4 cycle latency = 6 FMAs in flight). So any cycle an FMA didn't run when its inputs were ready is a cycle missed in that dep chain, with no slack to catch up.

See Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)

@PeterCordes: Thanks, I'll definitely read your answer there! (already upvoted it). My worry was based on that for smaller unrolls, the compiler first read all of x into registers (I mean all of x which is processed by the current iteration), and then updated all the accumulators. So this way needs the amount of 2 x number_of_accumulators registers. But I understand that this approach is not mandatory, the compiler can just read some part of x, update some of the accumulators, and the read the remaining x, and update the remaining accumulators.

Exactly; compilers should be smart enough to schedule instructions to avoid spills.  But even 8 accumulators would have room to load all the x temporaries, since we can see it's already folding the y loads into source operands for FMAs.  (Or vice versa; I didn't check.)

@PeterCordes: Using 8 accumulators, it runs 2.6 vs 3.77 sec. It's crazy, the difference between the versions even larger.

I changed the code to use 8 accumulators and it ran 5% slower on my i7 6700. This level of optimisation can be quite architecture specific I think.

@geza: Between versions?  Or between slow vs. fast runs of the same 8-accumulator version?

@PeterCordes: same 8-accumulator version, fast run is 2.6, slow is 3.77. So with the 4-accumulator version, we have 4.2/3.4 = ~1.26. 8-accumulator version: 3.77/2.6 = 1.45.

@SimonGoater: Did you do How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc? for your Skylake?  (Only Skylake-derived CPUs are affected at all by that, won't affect geza's CPU, only ours.)

@PeterCordes No I didn't. Wasn't aware of it. I modified the code a bit to make it c. My gcc doesn't recognise the flag gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mbranches-within-32B-boundaries’. Same for -mno-....Will look again tomorrow. What is the difference on yours? Mine's Skylake without AVX512.

It would be interesting if someone with a CPU of the same generation would confirm or refute these variations. I think maybe Intel need to look into this if it's reproducible on other CPUs.
